# How can I redirect specific URLs ending in .PHP to another URL in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, joomla

If the URL ends in .HTML I have no problem controlling it and redirecting it within Joomla. But if ends in .PHP I get the 404 page.

I assume it can be fix one of two ways:
 1. Give Joomla control of URLs ending in PHP so that I can redirect the URL from within Joomla
or 
 2. Try to do it within the NGINX config:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /oldsignup.php {
   rewrite ^/.* http://example.com/signup.html permanent;
}

location /oldsignup2.php {
   rewrite ^/.* http://example.com/signup.html permanent;
}
```

I tried the above but it failed.

Comment: Can you please expand on "failed". What failed - did it do anything? What do the logs say? What you have you tried to address it - have you done debugging to see if the problem is the rewrite regex or the location block match regex?

Comment: @Tim Thanks I think I figured out how to do it with-in NGINX. Now I just need to figure out how to pass that control to the URL Rewrite Component within Joomla so I don't have to make these manual adjustments within the NGINX config.

Comment: A friendly suggestion - if it only takes you 15 minutes to work out the answer to a question, perhaps you should put in a little more effort before taking the time to post the question. Your call, of course, sometimes writing a question helps work out the answer.

Comment: You need quite a complex setup to pass the control of `.php` URLs to Joomla. First you would need to use `try_files /index.php$is_args$args;`, and then define `location` blocks for all static resources, where you would use `try_files $uri $uri/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
rewrite ^/oldsignup1.php$ http://example.com/signup.html permanent;
rewrite ^/oldsignup2.php$ http://example.com/signup.html permanent;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```